# Midas (DataSnap) Delphi application became much slower when run on Windows10

Tags: delphi, datasnap

We have an application developed under Delphi 5 using the Midas (DataSnap) technology. It uses TClientDataSet on the client side and TSocketConnection to connect to the server app. The client app and server app are on the same local network.

The client application got some 50% slower when moved to Windows 10. Our test setup consists of a server (SQL database + server layer application) and two clients: one under Windows7, another Windows10. Both clients run the same EXE and run the same query. The problem is that TClientDataSet on Windows10 is some 50% slower then opening.
Why does it happen???

We did disable FireWall, Windows Defender and any possible antivirus - without any visible difference to the performance of either.

My test loop is as below:

```
// Set parameters for the query     
ParamsQuery( VarArrayOf( ['PID','DISPENSEDATE'] ), VarArrayOf( [1234567, '2018-Sep-15' ] ) );  


for row := 1000 downto 0 do
begin
  DMDispensing.CDSTest.Close;
  DMDispensing.CDSTest.Open;
end;
```

Windows 7
   MSEC
   0 | DMDispensing         CDSTestBeforeOpen
   0 | DMDispensing         CDSTestBeforeGetRecords
   22 | DMDispensing         CDSTestAfterGetRecords
   3 | DMDispensing         CDSTestAfterOpen
   2 | DMDispensing         CDSTestBeforeClose
   0 | DMDispensing         CDSTestBeforeGetRecords
  0 | DMDispensing         CDSTestAfterGetRecords
  0 | DMDispensing         CDSTestAfterClose

```
Windows 10            
MSEC
0 | DMDispensing         CDSTestBeforeOpen    
0 | DMDispensing         CDSTestBeforeGetRecords 
31 | DMDispensing         CDSTestAfterGetRecords 
0 | DMDispensing         CDSTestAfterOpen     
0 | DMDispensing         CDSTestBeforeClose   
0 | DMDispensing         CDSTestBeforeGetRecords 
16 | DMDispensing         CDSTestAfterGetRecords
0 | DMDispensing         CDSTestAfterClose
```

So typically a single loop takes 27msec on Windows7 and 37msec on Windows10.

Comment: Does Delphi 5 already had the option to `use MidasLib` in your uses clause, so you dont have to install the dll ?

Comment: It may be related to the number of rows.  Approximately how many rows is your Sql query returning?

Comment: The test data has 10 records only

Comment: @MartynA 10 records only

Comment: If it's only 10 rows, I'm surprised you can even time it - it should be virtually instantaneous.  Do you get a similar difference in speeds if you execute the Sql using Sql Server Management Studio on the clients?  Which Sql driver are you using in your Dephi client.  You need to add an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your q to get help with this.

Comment: @MartynA Martyn, I remember to already use MidasLib in Delphi 6. https://books.google.es/books?id=9JzBn4vcUBoC&pg=PA360&lpg=PA360&dq=DELPHI+6+MIDASLIB&source=bl&ots=wARnMuotpU&sig=Meb-fZXyhsC2iHw1HvEYyrO5Rpg&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqxNS90PTeAhVCVsAKHcgUCWoQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=DELPHI%206%20MIDASLIB&f=false

Comment: @MartynA: MidasLib was available in the higher SKUs in early versions of Delphi (around D5 or so). It became available for all SKUs in D2007, IIRC.

Comment: @MartynA I use MidasLib in delphi 7 projects so its definitly there. I just don't remember if you could do it with `uses midaslib` in delphi 5 already

Comment: @MartynA The number of records returned is small, but we query many tables, then updated them etc - so it is constant flow of reasonably high number of queries - what is why we can see the difference.

Comment: @MartynA MS SQL server  v17. The same query run in the Management Studio on the client machine runs instantaneously - 00.00.00.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite, Marc & Guido G.  Obviously my memory regarding MidasLib is faulty ahd I'll delete my comment about it.

Comment: "but we query many tables, then update ..."  Well that's a bit different from a query only returning 10 rows.  Have you tried profiling your app with a good profiler like this one: https://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=node/27156?

Comment: @MartynA I tried to identify the problem so I added a test code behind one of the buttons. It used a TClientDataSet component what is not used anywhere in the code (no UI elements connected). I open it and close it in a loop. I log only some events for each loop.

Comment: Is the debugger running on W7 box and not on W10 box? Or, how are you timing? I'm asking because W10 timing look like suspiciously multiples of 15,625ms.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The timing is produced at run time by the application - we are just writing lines of text into a text file. The timing is from the previous line to the current line. No debugger was running here.

Comment: @Tomasz - I rather meant to ask how is your application measuring the timing. W10 timing look like it can be GetTickCount or some sort of threaded timer utilizing Sleep. Just be sure to use something that will make sense for such short periods, like [QPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396). I asked the IDE because it calls timeBeginPeriod and increases timeGetTime/Sleep resolution to 1ms.

Comment: @MartynA New observation: sometimes the client application runs much faster on Windows10 too. But once you reboot the PC, it returns to the old, sluggish ways. We compared services running before and after the boot. There were 5 less running after the reboot. We started them manually but the speed didn't improve.It happens sometimes but always the reboot brings the old slow behaviour back - we can't figure out what makes  a difference.